# What's this stud type called and how should I drill for hanging a heavy item?

Tags: mounting, studs, television

I just moved into a new house and doing my research, learning and planning before hanging a mount for a 40lb TV.

I have a Mantel Mount, which is basically a lowering mount to be hung over the fireplace.

I found out today that the studs are positioned in a way I haven't seen before. Its double studs and the narrower side is towards the wall, where I have to drill. Below is a photo, I tried my best to zoom into the area and highlight the studs, but I'll be happy to answer any question and describe them better if there's a need. (questions after the photo)

[image: Photo of the studs.]

How do I properly drill into this for hanging such a heavy thing? Should I aim for the center, right were both studs stick with each other? Or is there a known trick for such type of stud arrangement?

Comment: While a little late but still feasible , talk to your builder about the mount you plan on using. They can install blocking or framing that will make attaching the frame where you want it much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is  pretty standard double-stud, used in this case to provide some extra support for the framing around your fireplace.

You should install like with a regular stud, and **do not try to guide your screw between the two studs.** The two studs are probably just nailed together in a few spots, and a screw driven in between them could spread them apart. You want each screw to go directly into one of the studs, ideally toward the center of one. You can also attach to the central (single) stud for your TV mount.

As @bib and @mikes point out, because your mount moves you will want to make sure it's firmly mounted at multiple points. If it can attach across two or three of these studs (not just the two that are doubled up, but spanning the gaps) great. If not, see if your builder can add some blocking to support the mount.

Comment: His mount sounds like a heavy duty unit, if it is one that lowers, and moving mounts generate a lot more stress. I would not limit a mount to one stud. since the walls are open, I would build a cross brace to attach the mount to.

Comment: Thanks. I installed it with mounting two screws per stud pair, on two studs. So, 4 screws in total. Also, picture is 8 months old so I had to make do with what I have.